# KVM - Oracle Linux 8 - RAC Installation (Private IP Problem)

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, oracle-linux

KVM virtualization is running on 2 different physical servers. Each of the nodes will run on a physical machine. Oracle RAC installation will be done on OL 8.x operating system as KVM Guest.

I want to set private IP for each guest (to be used for cluster interconnect). For example; 10.10.10.1 for Node-1 and 10.10.10.2 for Node-2.

For this, I created an isolated network on each physical machine (a total of 2 isolated networks, one on each machine) and assigned the IPs to the guest machines. KVM guest machines can ping their own IPs, they cannot ping each other's private IPs. For cluster interconnect, they need to be pinged (i.e. accessed by each other).

I'm not an expert on this, how can I get over it?